# Spring Data - data is loaded but not persisted

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I'm trying to use Spring Data for the first time. I've created my repository interface for Spring to implement. I use `findAll()` method, and it works well. However, `save()` and `delete()` methods don't work as I expect: no data is persisted, though no exception is thrown.

I tried to debug through Hibernate code, and I see event `EntityDeleteAction[com.my.test.City#2]` is added to the ActionQueue, but its `execute()` method is not called. And I did not manage to find out why.

Could you help me please? Below is database creation code, java config, my entity and repository code:

```
CREATE TABLE cities(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
INSERT INTO cities(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Moscow');
INSERT INTO cities(id, name) VALUES (2, 'St.Petersburg');
```

City.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    public String name;
}
```

CityRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {}
```

AppConfig.java (part)

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = ...)
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.my.test.repository")
@Import(value = {
        SecurityConfig.class,
        WebMvcConfig.class
})
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
    sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.my.test");
    sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(
            "com.my.test.repository",
            "com.my.test.entity"
    );
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    return em;
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    return properties;
}
```

Method I execute:

```
cityRepository.delete(2);
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: From where are you running this `cityRepository.delete(2)`;

Comment: You are using the wrong transaction manager. You are using JPA so you need to use the `JpaTransactionManager` not the `HibernateTransactionManager`.

Comment: M. Denium, you're right! This helped. Would you post it as an answer so I could mark it as a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M. Deinum wrote, the issue was in incorrect transaction manager. This was the solution:

delete bean `sessionFactory()`

replace beans:

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    em.setPackagesToScan(
            "com.my.test.repository",
            "com.my.test.entity"
    );
    em.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return em;
}
```

Comment: I would use 'AClassFromThatPackage.class.getPackage().getName()' instead of 'com.my.test.entity'. It is less fragile for refactoring this way.

Comment: Nice idea, Tomas, I always disliked these string literals